# Is there a way to write this code in a more succinct and proper way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, boolean, logic

For the following CodingBat problem:

> When squirrels get together for a party, they like to have `cigars`. A
> squirrel party is successful when the number of `cigars` is between 40
> and 60, inclusive. Unless it is the weekend, in which case there is no
> upper bound on the number of cigars. Return `True` if the party with the
> given values is successful, or `False` otherwise.

I wrote the following answer:

```
def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
  if is_weekend and cigars >= 40:
    return True
  if not is_weekend and (cigars >= 40 or cigars <= 60):
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

And my asnwer is not working as expected with the following inputs:

```
cigar_party(30, False) 
cigar_party(61, False) 
cigar_party(39, False)
```

Comment: Can you explain when `cigars >= 40 or cigars <= 60` would not be true? Hint: you need an `and` instead of an `or` there.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
  if is_weekend and cigars >= 40:
    return True
  elif 40 <= cigars <= 60 and not is_weekend:
    return True
  return False

def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
  if cigars >= 40:
    if is_weekend or cigars <= 60:
      return True
  return False
```

If you use a not before a compound predicate, the whole thing is negated.
Technically it could be a one liner using ternary operator syntax but that line would probably not be PEP8 compliant in terms of length.

Depending on your use case, you could also technically omit the "return False" because the bool of None is False.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you test for `cigars >= 40 or cigars <= 60`. For an integer input, this condition is always true--either `cigars` is greater than or equal to 40, or `cigars` is less than or equal to 60. What I assume you meant to test is that `cigars >= 40 and cigars <= 60`. Indeed, if you make just that change, your code functions perfectly well: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBDoIwEEX3nGKWkLDAFGswlqUncE8aGbTRFFJKDKevQF0UIdBFk8mf9/9Mp@n1s5bEmBIruIsHV0XDle7DqW5jEG3xQXyhLKNzACAqRwE@PAtCziBNRgJAoe6UhJvq0Dpkrf9doWtzcy4MaBKtBeG7xZl@5YNiGiWkDt3VSRLbXgSM/apgiR1n2DhkjToN1NTbgogLbQ7cjaJeW9GD1xdTrzCSeYftXyJbXMJ8AQ)

However, if you're asking for "succinct and proper", I would suggest that you either break the problem down into two simple cases:

```python
def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
  if is_weekend:
    return cigars >= 40
  else:
    return 40 <= cigars <= 60
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSE5Mz2xKL4gsaikUgPMLtZRyCyOL09NzU7NS9G04lJQyExDEgEJKCgUpZaUFuVBNBcr2NkqmBgAxVNzilNR5E0MFGxsYaqALDOD/wVFmXklGsi2GhvoKLglArVqKtjaQllcmMpMUZSFFJViVWUOVAWWw6fIGFkRXgsJGmVGlKvMDInyoglRhhlbEm0Y4ZCwxAiJ/wA)

or use a single expression, which parallels the wording of the specification quite pleasantly:

```python
def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
  return cigars >= 40 and (is_weekend or cigars <= 60)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBCsIwEEX3PcUsE@iikhqpmC49gfsSTNSgpGGSIj19lKpYqbTZDfzHm5nv@nBpLYtR6RMczVli4ySGngyzz8H45q71VVtFtxkA6tChfZEeagFlAdIqIF8OWvzkOwG8oNGhsYGM7azIYS9vXlMQ4j1lU2z9gx2w@0ttntSQzUFsDM0uXFTxpKv4KunFMknGqmTZchPVpIn4AA)